# Login and logout sometimes only visible after pages refresh

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.6

I already searched for all the topics, and nothing helped. In my Laravel installation, you sometimes have to reload the page after login and logout to make it visible. Very rarely you are not logged in or out at all.

I use Laravel 5.6.39.

**Login Controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

**config/session.php**

```php
return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => true,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => 'mysql',
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '').'session'
    ),

    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => null,
];
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.php** middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I also tried to change the cookie name, define the cookie domain, change the session from file to database. Nothing helped.

Edit:
I just compared the session database with the cookie. In the database I have the right status with the comparison to the cookie, only Laravel himself says that you are not logged in or logged out.

My `RedirectIfAuthenticated` is unchanged

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check your `redirectifUnauthenticated` middleware.

Comment: My RedirectIfAuthenticated.php. It's unchanged.

`<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}`

Comment: Add that to the question too please.

Comment: I added it @Jalil, he'll need to valid the edit ;)

Comment: Watch out your cache system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassing mistake. PHP-FPM was activated in the server settings, which put complete PHP requests into the cache. Without FPM the Laravel page works as wished.